# How to change the String in Java

Tags: java, android, string, variables, substring

I need to rename String variable as below

```
String name = 20161018_175737_groupX_nameY.png;
```

into

```
String name = Background_groupX_nameY.png;
```

Any kind of help is appreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: name.replace("20161018_175737","Background");

Comment: Try explaining a little bit better... because there are something like 90909085414093425894 possible solutions for the question you asked..

Comment: Is that supposed to be a sting literal on the RHS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys. There are many solution. This is my one.

```
StringBuffer strBffer= new StringBuffer(fileName);
strBffer.replace(0, 15, "Background");
String newName = strBffer.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression will help you best:

```
 name = name.replaceFirst("\\d+_\\d+", "Background");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ..

```
String name = "20161018_175737_groupX_nameY.png";
name = name.substring(name.indexOf("_",name.indexOf("_")+1),name.length());
System.out.print("Background"+name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to identify a sequence of digits followed by an underscore, followed by another sequence of digits, followed by another underscore and replace it with an empty string:

```
name = name.replaceFirst("\\d+_\\d+_", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to find the string portion need to be replaced

```
String name = "20161018_175737_groupX_nameY.png";
String matchString="";
for(int index=0;index<name.length();index++){
   if(name.substring(0,index).matches("^[0-9]+[\\_]{1}[0-9]+[\\_]{1}$")){
       matchString=name.substring(0,index);
       break;
   }
}
name=name.replaceFirst(matchString,"Background_");
```

Answer (score 0):

- If replaceble part is not uniform (can be whatever not just numbers with underscore) but _groupX_nameY.png is constant then you can:

```
name.replaceFirst("^.*(?=(_groupX_nameY.png))", "background");
```

- It selects everything up to the provided string (excluding in this case '_groupX_nameY.png') and replacing it with 'background'